# Embed external CSS in Flex's swf file

Tags: css, apache-flex, stylesheet, embedded-resource

I want a few Flex (SDK 4.6) applications to share the same stylesheet (stored in CSS file). However I do not want to distribute standalone file along those applications' SWFs, but rather want to embed the CSS file into Flex application file (just as you embed images etc.). CSS declarations include font-embeddings so it is (I think) impossible to load CSS at runtime.

What I already found out:

1. I cannot simply use `<fx:Script source="@Embed(stylesheet.css)" />`. Wrong syntax.
2. I cannot use inline stylesheet in some MXML component that is shared among applications because CSS contains type declarations which are not allowed in components.
3. I can choose to compile CSS to SWF but this creates standalone SWF file (so I can embed Flex framework into SWF but not a standalone CSS ;]).

I hope I am missing something obvious and this is fairly easy to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a library project (producing a swc file)
- Add the stylesheet as a resource
- Put this project (or the compiled swc) on your other project's build path
- You can now use this resource from within your other projects:
  `<fx:Style source="stylesheet.css" />`

As an **example**:
In the librabry project you have `src/stylesheet.css`
If `src` is a source folder, the file should automatically be packaged into the library
If it's not, you'll have to manually add the files: in FlashBuilder this can be done through the `Assets` tab of the `Build path` editor. On the command line, add it with the `-include-file` option.

An **alternative** to using the swc as a library dependency, is to define it as a **theme** dependency. In FlashBuilder there's a `Theme` wizard in the project properties. On the command line do:

```
mxmlc -theme="/path/to/my/theme.swc" MyApp.mxml
```

If you use it as a theme, you don't even have to include the `fx:Style` tag in your Application. The CSS is included by default. But I think it *has* to be named `defaults.css`.

Comment: This bothers me: why is CSS file automatically included in "Library" project (SWC) and not in "Application" project (SWF)? Any idea? :]

Comment: A `.swf` is one file that contains all the compiled bytecode (somewhat like Java `.class` files). A `.swc` on the other hand is nothing more than an archive (like a `.zip` or Java `.jar` file) that contains the `.swf` with the bytecode of the library, plus any other files you want to add to it, like a CSS file. Thus, by its very nature a `.swf` cannot contain other files, and CSS is an interpreted language and cannot be compiled (hence it cannot be compiled into the swf).

Comment: But couldn't `.swf` contain CSS file just as it can contain image files? And if you link `.swc` into final `.swf` then this final `.swf` effectively contains original CSS isn't it? :]

Comment: Thanks, RIAstar, I'll give your solution a try, but personally its quite an overhead to build a library to embed a simple CSS file... :-)

Comment: @KubaWyrostek When you embed an image file into a `swf`, you do not include the file itself, but its content. The image is serialized to a ByteArray which is assigned to a variable and all of this is compiled as bytecode. I suppose in theory you could compile the content of the CSS file too (as a String variable in this case) and load this String as a style declaration, but this loading can only be done at runtime.